# Estimating this integral

Tags: complex-analysis

In a book I am reading it states that the integral $I(R) = \int_0^\xi e^{-\pi(R^2 + 2iRy - y^2)}idy$ goes to 0 as $R \rightarrow \infty$ since $\xi$ is fixed we can estimate the integral by $|I(R)| \leq Ce^{-\pi R^2}.$ How did they get this estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
|I(R)| \le \int_0^\xi |e^{-\pi(R^2 + 2iRy - y^2)}|dy=\int_0^\xi e^{-\pi(R^2- y^2)}dy=e^{-\pi R^2}\int_0^\xi e^{\pi y^2}dy\le e^{-\pi R^2}\cdot e^{\pi \xi^2}\xi.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing $\xi >0$ and real: then $y \ge 0$ is real as well. Recalling that $|e^z|= e^{\mathrm{Re} z}$, you have
$$|e^{- \pi (R^2-y^2+i2Ry)}| = e^{ \pi y^2-\pi R^2} \le e^{ \pi \xi^2-\pi R^2}$$
So that
$$\left| \int_0^{\xi} e^{- \pi (R^2-y^2+i2Ry)} i \mathrm{d} y\right| \le \int_0^{\xi} |e^{- \pi (R^2-y^2+i2Ry)}| \mathrm{d} y \le
\int_0^{\xi} e^{ \pi \xi^2-\pi R^2} \mathrm{d} y = \xi e^{ \pi \xi^2-\pi R^2}$$

Can you go on from here?